# How to check the privacy setting ("only me" or "friends") for publish_actions permission using Facebook Open Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I ask users of my app for publish_actions permission just before publishing and action on their wall:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}, { scope: 'publish_actions' });
```

Some people choose "only me" in the permissions dialog.

I would like to find out, how many people do that, in order to optimise the way and point in time i ask for the permission.

**NOTE:** I have heard that it is possible to find that out by querying the API after publishing the action:

```
FB.api('/' + published_action_id, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

but the `response` doesn't contain the "privacy" object (any more?).

Comment: Did you ever figure it out??